# Reply to a different email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have some partners that have several email addresses. I can reach them only with one of these addresses. Is it possible to configure Outlook 2019 that my reply is always sent to one of the addresses?

Example:

- Guy.Harris@foo.com
- Guy.Harris@bla.com
- GHarris@foo.com

All addresses are valid. Guy can send with any of them. But he only reads the mail from `GHarris@foo.com`. I want Outlook to send to `GHarris@foo.com` when I click "reply" even if the sender's address is `Guy.Harris@foo.com`, or `Guy.Harris@bal.com`. How can I configure this reply-to-scheme?

Note: This is not a question how I configure the Reply-To email address that others should use to send me an answer. I really want Outlook to behave as if Guy always had the

> Reply-To: GHarris@foo.com"

applied to all his mails.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when you click reply to, the "To" field will just display the email sender. I'm afraid it can't be set as the same address.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the mail in the sender field or you can compose a new mail with new sender address - to give it a continuity to the mail you can put the previous mail in reference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, please read:  `I really want Outlook to behave as if Guy always had the  (reply-to-address) applied to all his mails.`